# virtualbox with webinterface (headless ubuntu server)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, headless

i have  extensively tested "virtualbox" on my Windows computer. I was convinced! Now I want to deploy a Linux computer systems use different windows. I imagine a headless machine. Are there experiences in this regard?

my "spare" computer:

AMD 2.4ghz,
2gb ram,
500gb hdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research, I chose the following solution:

Host system:

- [ubuntu 12.04 server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)
- [virtualbox-ose](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/VirtualBox/Installation)
- [phpvirtualbox](http://code.google.com/p/phpvirtualbox/downloads/detail?name=phpvirtualbox-4.1-7.zip)

Answer (score 1):

if your system supports hardware visualization I'd recommend proxmox over virtualbox.
Proxmox is an entire OS/vs/web interface all in one installable ISO image.

quick check if the machine is already running Linux would be:

```
egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
```

if you get 0 then either it doesn't or its turned off in the bios if you get 1 or higher then your good to go. but KVM (kernel virtual machine) will give you greater performance over virtualbox. KVM also allows you to actually connect a guest system to a physical hard drive instead of a virtual one (major performance boost)

Answer (score 0):

You probably realise this, but you might very soon run out of memory if you want to do anything non-trivial with your guests.

I use ubuntu 12.04 for a virtualbox server, the command line tools take a while to get used to, but they do the job well. You might also find Ubuntu Cloud interesting.